# Tabular Endnotes

Tags: endnotes

I am using the `endnotes.sty` to create the author queries to be printed on all the endnotes article firstpage.

I need a tabular endnote format in `\theendnotes` output. I don't know how to change the endnotes.sty to reach the required output. Please advice.

MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{vruler}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


% ------------- comment this at the first run -------------
\AtBeginDocument{\theendnotes\clearpage%
  \setvruler[10pt][1][1][4][1][0pt][0pt][0pt][\textheight]}
%----------------------------------------------------------




\begin{document}

\title{Sample document for endnotes}
\author[1,]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\maketitle

\noindent Patterning\endnote{Sample Query Endnote One} in Arabidopsis root development
is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum in the
root tip (Sabatini et al., 1999), requiring the regulated expression
of speciÞc genes. This auxin gradient has been hypothesized to be sink-driven (Friml et al., 2002) and com- putational modeling suggests that auxin efßux carrier activity may be sufÞcient to generate the gradient in the absence of auxin biosynthesis\endnote{Sample Query Endnote Two} in the root (Grieneisen et al., 2007; Wabnik et al., 2010). However, other experimental studies show that local auxin biosynthesis modulates gradient- directed planar polarity in Arabidopsis, and a local source of auxin biosynthesis contributes to auxin gradient homeostasis (Ikeda et al., 2009). Thus genetic studies show that auxin biosynthesis (Ikeda et al., 2009; Normanly, 2010; Zhao, 2010), the AUX1/LAX inßux carriers (Swarup et al., 2005, 2008; Jones et al., 2008; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010), and the PIN auxin efux carri- ers (Petr‡sek et al., 2006; Grieneisen et al., 2007; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010; Mironova et al., 2010) all play important roles in the formation of auxin gradients. In addition, experimental evidence shows that, in root devel- opment, hormones and the associated regulatory and target genes form a network, in which relevant genes regulate hormone activ- ities and hormones regulate gene expression. For example, ethy- lene promotes auxin ßux in the root, in a process dependent on the POLARIS (PLS) peptide (Ruzicka et al., 2007; Swarup et al., 2007; Liu et al., 2010a). Furthermore, PIN levels are positively reg- ulated by ethylene and auxin in Arabidopsis roots (Ruzicka et al., 2007). Interestingly, cytokinin can negatively regulate PIN lev- els (Ruzicka et al., 2009), while repressing auxin biosynthesis and promoting ethylene responses (Nordstrom et al., 2004; Chandler, 2009; Liu et al., 2010a). Cytokinin also has the capacity to mod- ulate auxin transport, by transcriptional regulation of the PIN genes (Ruzicka et al., 2009).

\begin{figure}[!t]
\caption{The sample caption\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure}\endnote{Sample Query Endnote Three}
\end{document}
```

Currently I am getting this below mentioned endnote output:

[image]

My Required tabular output below mentioned here:

[image]

I don't know how to make the changes in `endnotes.sty` to get this required output.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Vetri It may be completely clear to you what you need. But I read it and wonder where the `\theendnotes` command may be defined to which end. Please, make a minimal working example ("MWE").

Comment: @keksDose I edit and save my question. Kindly share your knowledge for this question

Comment: That won't work with tabular: If there are more endnotes than space on the page, those endnotes are outside of the page. So you would need using longtable or supertabular and a major hack of endnotes.sty. I don't the skills to write that. But let me ask: Why is it important to have a lot of lines around an endnote? What is the purpose of placing endnotes in a long table?